# how to sort 3 strings with only 3 if statement (C++)

Tags: c++, string, sorting, if-statement

I need help comparing 3 strings but using only 3 if statements

I was able to write using 5 if statements

I will be very grateful if anyone knows how to solve it

```
string a, b, c;
if( a>b && a>c ){
  if(b>c)
    cout << a << b << c;
  else
    cout << a << c << b;
}
else if( b>c && b>a ){
  if(a>c)
    cout << b << a << c;
  else
    cout << b << c << a;
}
else{
   if(a>b)
    cout << c << a << b;
  else
    cout << c << b << a;
}
```

Comment: Use [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) instead of some of the `if`s?

Comment: If you want to actually sort the strings (reorder their values), it can be done with 3 `if` statements.

Answer (score 3):

If you are allowed to swap the strings then the code can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    std::string a( "2" ), b( "1" ), c( "3" );
    
    if ( b < a ) std::swap( a, b );
    if ( c < b ) std::swap( b, c );
    if ( b < a ) std::swap( a, b );
    
    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3
```

If you are not allowed to swap the strings you can use objects of the type `std::reference_wrapper`. Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

int main() 
{
    std::string a( "2" ), b( "1" ), c( "3" );
    auto ra = std::cref( a ), rb = std::cref( b ), rc = std::cref( c );
        
    if ( rb.get() < ra.get() ) std::swap( ra, rb );
    if ( rc.get() < rb.get() ) std::swap( rb, rc );
    if ( rb.get() < ra.get() ) std::swap( ra, rb );
    
    std::cout << ra.get() << ' ' << rb.get() << ' ' << rc.get() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

```
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 3 2-way branches will separate the execution path to only 4 ways, so it is impossible to use only 3 2-way branches to generate 6 putterns of output.

One workaround is using [ternary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) instead of some of the `if`s.

```
string a, b, c;
if( a>b && a>c ){
  b>c ? cout << a << b << c : cout << a << c << b;
}
else if( b>c && b>a ){
  a>c ? cout << b << a << c : cout << b << c << a;
}
else{
   if(a>b)
    cout << c << a << b;
  else
    cout << c << b << a;
}
```

Another option is encoding the comparision result to one integer and using `switch` to generate proper output according to the result.

```
string a, b, c;
int res = 0;
if(a>b) res += 1;
if(a>c) res += 2;
if(b>c) res += 4;
switch(res){
    case 0: // a<=b && a<=c && b<=c
        cout << b << c << a;
        break;
    case 1: // a>b && a<=c && b<=c
        cout << c << a << b;
        break;
    case 2: // a<=b && a>c && b<=c
        // invalid
        break;
    case 3: // a>b && a>c && b<=c
        cout << a << c << b;
        break;
    case 4: // a<=b && a<=c && b>c
        cout << b << c << a;
        break;
    case 5: // a>b && a<=c && b>c
        // invalid
        break;
    case 6: // a<=b && a>c && b>c
        cout << b << a << c;
        break;
    case 7: // a>b && a>c && b>c
        cout << a << b << c;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a>b && a>c){
  (b>c)?cout << a << b << c:cout << a << c << b;
}
else if( b>c && b>a ){
  (a>c)?cout << b << a << c:cout << b << c << a;
}
else{
   (a>b)?cout << c << a << b:cout << c << b << a;
}
```

You could try ternary operators for the nested if-else cases

Comment: In general the code is not correct. That is for some values it will output wrong sequences.